# Jquery window.unload event called after controller action when refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a page when a content is edited. when a user comes to this edit page we lock the content by setting IsLocked = true and when a user navigates to different page we unlock it by using Jquery window.unload event.

This works fine in all cases. But when we refresh the page the controller gets called first and after that window.Unload event is called.

So in this way the content gets locked first and then gets unlocked.

Any suggestions to identify the page refresh and restrict unlocking of the content?
or how to call the jquery.unload event before controller action?

```
$(window).on('unload',function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'unlockcontent' + contentId
        async: false,
        success: function () {
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What happens if you use $(document) instead of $(window)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `beforeunload` event instead of the `unload` event.

Comment: Tried with beforeUnload but it didn't worked for us.